# Separating array into different variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array getting to from jquery to my php page, 
into total they are 20 strings in the array, some of which are empty.

*an example if one of the array*

```
array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "KI"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "GY"
    }
```

In php I get the array like

```
if (isset($_POST[access_array])) {
   $access = isset($_POST[access_array]) ? $_POST[access_array] :NULL ;
}
```

and they I check to see if it is empty like

```
foreach( $access as $key => $value ) {
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2 ) {
            if( empty( $value2 ) ) 
                unset( $access[ $key ][ $key2 ] );
        }
    }
    if( empty( $access[ $key ] ) )
        unset( $access[ $key ] );
}
```

what I am trying to do now is, access those strings in the array into variables
like

```
$array_string1 = 
$array_string2 =
$array_string3 = 
$array_string4 = 
$array_string5 =
blah
blah
$array_string20 =
```

and then check to see if any of the `$array_string`(s) is empty before running an insert statement which will store the data like

```
table: lvl

id   name    arraystring
1    john     'HI','HT','OP'   <---- that is just any example so HI will be `$array_string1`, HT `$array_string2` or `$array_string18`. Something like that.
```

The issue I am facing how is separating the strings in the array into those `$array_string`(s) variables. 
I have seen similar questions(same title) but no specify answers

Comment: Why exactly would you want them to be in several variables? What output exactly do you get from the JavaScript?

Comment: what exactly is your question? are you looking to convert array into string?

Comment: No, you do not want this. You have a nice array there which you can access via `$array[1]`. Where in the world is the advantage in doing `$array1` instead? Also: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: Well then do `$access[0]`, `$access[1]` etc. Where's the problem?

Comment: @deceze thanks, I was over thinking this. Wanted to do something that was complex when they was an easier way

Comment: @deceze just one more question. I hope you saw the way I needed to insert the data in the array. with the method u just shown me. It will not way in the way I am thinking of doing it. because i will need to do `$access[0], $access[1], blah, blah $access[19], $access[20]. which might insert spaces in the column

Comment: @deceze because this is how I think might work ` $access_full = $access[0] . "','" .$access[1] ."','".$access[2];`

Comment: `$access_full = join(',', array_filter($access))`

Comment: @deceze thanks again, I really appreciate your help. Thanks to everyone who helped and try to answer this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is dangerous in case the array key names are coming from the web... They might try and overwrite important, already used keys. (Somewhat like Magic GPC, which is now also deprecated.)

**So actually I really DO NOT recommend this**

But you could do something like this:

```
$array = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "bear");
print_r($array); // echoes:
//Array
//(
//    [a] => apple
//    [b] => bear
//)

foreach ($array as $key=>$val)
    $$key = $val;

echo $a; // echoes apple
echo $b; // echoes bear
```

Comment: are u referring to the second foreach statement?

Comment: @user3057514 I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry if I was alittle confusing but what I wanted to ask was I wanted to know for the answer your provided. was this about my second `foreach` statement or just for all the `foreach` statement